# How to identify the source of what com.apple.launchd is attempting to run

Tags: macos, mongodb, launchd

The system log on my Mac Mini is showing this error in the system log:

```
Mar  7 17:51:18 My-Mac-mini com.apple.launchd[1] (org.mongodb.mongod[432]): posix_spawn("/opt/local/bin/mongod", ...): No such file or directory
Mar  7 17:51:18 My-Mac-mini com.apple.launchd[1] (org.mongodb.mongod[432]): Exited with code: 1
Mar  7 17:51:18 My-Mac-mini com.apple.launchd[1] (org.mongodb.mongod): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

I have install MONGODB using Brew, and it works properly.

I have used LOCATE to attempt to track the source of the launching PLIST (I guess).

How do I track the source of what Apple's "launchd" is attempting to run?

Comment: I had MacPorts installed but switched to Homebrew.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can search the LaunchDaemons folders for that job label:

```
grep -Rl ">org\.mongodb\.mongod<" /System/Library/LaunchDaemons /Library/LaunchDaemons
```

(Note: the backslashes and angle-brackets in the search string are needed to avoid false matches, and if you don't have them wrapped in double-quotes, you'll get unexpected results.)

If it's installed using the standard conventions, it should be in /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mongodb.mongod.plist, but this command should find it whatever it's named.

Once you've found it, you can disable it with:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.mongodb.mongod.plist
```

(Or whatever the actual file path is.)  If you want, you can also remove the file, but the `-w` option makes the unload permanent so that isn't really necessary.

Comment: Looks like that command worked. Thanks! And now I know where to look for LaunchDaemons.

Comment: @Elcidia:  Great!  Since it worked, please mark this as the "accepted" answer (see the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... did you have it installed with Macports at one time? Cause that looks like the location for the ports installation of it (whereas i would expect brew to put it in /usr/local). If that is the case then try doing

```
sudo port unload mongodb
```

and that should unload the posts specific plist which is probably registered to load at boot time. If you're going to use Brew id probably set about clearing out ports completely.

Comment: Yes, I did install Macports at one time. I am not sure I ever cleaned up the remnants. Maybe I should ask a question about removing traces of Macports? :)